# Change page via BroadcastReceiver does not work

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make a second page show up via a BroadcastReceiver, but the App keeps crashing and I don't know why.
This might be a problem of the correct context.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.v("$$$$$", "In Method: ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    Log.v("$$$$$", "In Method: ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
            changeActivity(context);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
                    Log.v("$$$$$", "In Method: USER_PRESENT");
        }
    }

public void changeActivity(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Second_Page.class);

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My Manifest. In there I declare the class that the log file states is missing:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CatchUnlockActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="second_page" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your system log (logcat) will contain the stack trace at the time of the crash. If you post that, the quality and quantity of responses will improve significantly.

Comment: You are right, should have done that.
My bad.
Here it is:
http://pastebin.com/eCr90iV9
Seems I am missing a class declaration!? But the class is declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
The declaration of the classes is **case-sensitive!**

Changed every occurrence from "second_page" to "Second_Page" and now it works.